# javascript load dynamically css and js files

Tags: javascript, laravel

I am using laravel 4 and I have a file style-switcher.js

yepnope([

```
{load: 'assets/css/style-switcher.css' },
{load: 'assets/lib/colorpicker/css/colorpicker.css'},
{
    load: 'assets/css/colorpicker_hack.css'
},
{
    load: 'assets/lib/cssbeautify/cssbeautify.js'
},
{
    load: 'assets/lib/colorpicker/js/bootstrap-colorpicker.js',
```

How can I load this css file dynamically? How to include the base path? For header and footer js and css I use

```
`{{ HTML::script('assets/...`) }}
```

But can't do the same with this js file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change the href of the css style tag

```
<link id="dynamic css" href="/old_css_path">
$('#dynamic_css').attr('href','/new_css_path')
```

or

if you want to append a new css, without removing other,
    $('head').append('')

no need to include base path of your website, just make sure you add backslash in starting of ever css path.

Comment: I didn't get it I want to change {load: 'assets/css/style-switcher.css' }, whith a path that gets base path. Because this file will be loaded in different pages and if the base url changes it doesn't find it. For example at / it loads it, but /cars doesn't

Comment: I tried with backslash but it still doesn't finds it. Please could you explain better what you mean. Because you are saying to change the link in css and than $('#dynamic_css').attr('href','/new_css_path'). but what to put here {load: 'assets/css/style-switcher.css' }, ???